# Adding 2D matrices as numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I want to add two 3x2 matrices, `g` and `temp_g`.

Currently `g` is

```
[[  2.77777778e+000   6.58946653e-039]
 [  4.96398713e+173   1.64736663e-039]
 [ -1.88888889e+000  -3.29473326e-039]]
```

And `temp_g` is:

```
[[ -5.00000000e-01  -2.77777778e+00]
 [ -1.24900090e-16  -4.44444444e-01]
 [  5.00000000e-01   1.88888889e+00]]
```

But when I do `g = g + temp_g`, and output `g`, I get this:

```
[[  2.27777778e+000  -2.77777778e+000]
 [  4.96398713e+173  -4.44444444e-001]
 [ -1.38888889e+000   1.88888889e+000]]
```

Maybe I'm having trouble understanding long float numbers... but is this what the result ought to be? I expected that `g[0][0]` would get added to `temp_g[0][0]`, and `g[0][1]` to `temp_g [0][1]` and so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your addition is working fine, but your two arrays have some **seriously** different orders of magnitude.

Taking for example `4.96398713e+173 - 1.24900090e-16`, your first number is 189 orders of magnitude bigger than the second. Floating point numbers don't have this level or accuracy, you're talking about talking a number with ~170 `0s` at the end of it and adding a number along the lines of `0.00000000000000001249` to it.

I would suggest looking at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) to see some of the limitations of floating point numbers (in all languages, not just necessarily Python).

The [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) library can be used for handling numbers more accurately than floats.

```
import numpy as np
import decimal

a = decimal.Decimal(4.96398713e+173)
b = decimal.Decimal(1.24900090e-16)

print(a+b)
# 4.963987129999999822073620193E+173

# You can also set the dtype of your array to decimal.Decimal
a = np.array([[  2.77777778e+000,   6.58946653e-039],
              [  4.96398713e+173,   1.64736663e-039],
              [ -1.88888889e+000, -3.29473326e-039]], 
             dtype=np.dtype(decimal.Decimal))
```

Comment: What's a good idea to use instead of floats then? Given that I will probably have lots of decimal places in my calculations (although probably not hundreds)

Comment: @user961627 I have edited my answer with details of the `Decimal` library which may help you.